# I can't bind json to the collection if an integer value exists in json in Power Apps

Tags: powerapps, dynamics-365, power-automate, powerapps-canvas

I get a text from power automate as JSON formatted.
The JSON is as below:

{"PurchaseOrderNumber":"PO00003871","LineNumber":1,"OrderedPurchaseQuantity":10}

I try to bind it a collection like below

```
ClearCollect(_purchlinesData, 
      MatchAll(GetPurchLineByPurchId.Run(_selectedPurcOrder.'Purchase order', _token.value).value, 
         "\{""ItemNumber"":""(?<ItemNumber>[^""]*)"",""PurchaseOrderNumber"":""(?<PurchaseOrderNumber>[^""]*),""OrderedPurchaseQuantity"":""(?<OrderedPurchaseQuantity>[^""]*)""\}"))
```

But it doesn't work. But If I remove the integer value which is 'OrderedPurchaseQuantity', it works.

How can I parse this JSON with integer variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the answer from the flow will always have the properties "PurchaseOrderNumber", "LineNumber" and "OrderedPurchaseQuantity" in this order, then you will need to have them in the same order if you want to use a regular expression to parse this answer:

```
ClearCollect(_purchlinesData, 
    Match(
        GetPurchLineByPurchId.Run(_selectedPurcOrder.'Purchase order', _token.value).value,
        "\{""PurchaseOrderNumber"":""(?<poNumber>[^""]*)"",""LineNumber"":(?<lineNumber>\d+),""OrderedPurchaseQuantity"":(?<purchaseQuantity>\d+)"))
```

Comment: Thank you, Carlos. Removing the quotes, and adding the \d+ end of the integer value. And It worked.

Answer (score 0):

Since `OrderedPurchaseQuantity` is an integer, what happens if you remove the double quotes around the value in the `MatchAll()` statement?

**From this...**
`""OrderedPurchaseQuantity"":""(?<OrderedPurchaseQuantity>[^""]*)""`

**To this...**
`""OrderedPurchaseQuantity"":(?<OrderedPurchaseQuantity>[^""]*)`

Because there will not be a time when the value is a string, so I could see why `MatchAll()` would fail here.

Comment: Thank you, SeaDude. I try that but It still doesn't work. What can else I use instead of MatchAll?